# Docker + Laravel: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

Me encuentro ante un problema que no he podido resolver y por ahora me encuentro bloqueado.

Tengo una aplicación en Laravel que necesita PHP-7.2. Pensé en realizar un contenedor en docker para poder utilizar el aplicativo pero a la hora de tratar de ingresar al aplicativo por el navegador me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

Cosa que no entiendo porque no quiero acceder por ssl de ninguna forma, simplemente quiero levantar el aplicativo y modificar algunas cosas.

Este es mi **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    webserver:
        image: 'nginx:alpine'
        working_dir: /www/html
        volumes:
            - '.:/www/html'
            - './phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf'
        ports:
            - '8080:80'

    php-fpm:
        build: phpdocker/php-fpm
        working_dir: /www/html
        volumes:
            - '.:/www/html'
            - './phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini'
```

Y este es mi **nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    client_max_body_size 108M;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;


    root /www/html/public;
    index index.php;

    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
}
```

Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes seteado APP_URL en el archivo .env?

Comment: Así: `https://localhost`

Comment: Ahí tienes el uso de ssl en el protocolo. Cambialo a `http://localhost`, limpia la cache y prueba otra vez

Comment: Ah, y el puerto es 8080, así que deberías setearlo a `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: El error persiste

Comment: Al final fue un problema de configuración del proyecto, el cual el programador anterior añadió unas variables que forzan al aplicativo a conectarse por ssl y https. Al añadirlas y setearlas en false, el aplicativo funciona. Esa era la respuesta.